# Rigify Error Bone cannot connect chain bone

Tags: rigging

Using rigify when generating the rig I get this error message Does someone know how I can fix this I don´t want to start it all over 
[image]

bone spine004 cannot connect chain bone position is disjoint. incorrect armature for type chain_rigs

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you move (separate) the spine.004 bone the error appears.
The bone spine.003 and spine.004 have to be perfectly aligned.

Steps (in edit mode):

1.- Selected bone spine.003
[image]

2.- MAY+S - Cursor to selected
[image]

3.- Select Spine.004 and  selection to cursor
[image]

4.- There is no more error and the rig is ok.
[image]

I hope I've helped.
R.

Comment: Just for noobs like me that come across this.
Step 2 - MAY+S = Shift+S
Also I had to do an extra step to get this to work - I had to select Spine 003 and choose Selection to Cursor.
Which doesn't make sense, because I'd previously move cursor to selection - but until I did that extra step, it wouldn't generate for me.

Comment: Note that you can move the end of Spine.003 to exactly coincide with the end of Spine.004 if you set snapping (at the top of the screen) to vertex and either switch it on or press CTRL while you move the end of the bone. This seems a bit simpler than using the 3D cursor

Comment: Alternatively: select Spine.003 and in the Bone Properties tab, Relations section tick the Connected check-box. Move the end of Spine.003 to where it should be, then un-tick the Connected check-box

Comment: I have also had to reparent neck bones to spine bones in the bird armature for some reason when encountering this error message.