# Blender 2.8: Rigify Error Bone cannot connect chain bone

Tags: animation, rigging, rigify

Please explain the reason of the error and solution for this

This is the disconnected joints

[image]

When i clicked the Generate Rig button

it give's me the error:

**Rigify Error: Bone 'spine.009': Cannot connect chain - bone position is disjoint. Incorrect armature for type 'chain_rigs'**

[image]

So i connected it.

[image]

But i still receive the error

**Rigify Error: Bone 'spine.009': Cannot connect chain - bone position is disjoint. Incorrect armature for type 'chain_rigs'**

I'm a software developer not an artist but i wan't to learn animation since it's pandemic right now. i want to create youtube videos so have a passive income.

Comment: The solution is found here. I'm too dumb.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/169555/rigify-error-bone-cannot-connect-chain-bone?rq=1

The "MAY+S" is SHIFT+S in windows

Comment: This is strange. Normally what you did should solve the error. Could you upload the model here?

 https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @CGDive Thank you for your time. i already solved the problem. i used the solution from here, https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/169555/rigify-error-bone-cannot-connect-chain-bone?rq=1