# Rigging - Bone 'spine.004 position disjointed

Tags: mesh, rigging, bones

[image]
Hi, when I press 'generate rig' this message appears. 'RIGIFY ERROR: Bone 'spine.004': Cannot connect chain - bone position is disjoint.' Incorrect armature for type 'chain_rigs'

Comment: This question is probably a duplicate of [Need help with Rigify in Blender v2.83 not working](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/199644/107598)  - it has the same error.

Comment: SOLUTION HERE:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/169555/rigify-error-bone-cannot-connect-chain-bone