Can't generate rig with Rigify after deleting some bones
I removed toes, ears and teeth since my model doesn't need them, but Rigify doesn't generate the rig without them.
I added these back in and altered the parents but I'm stuck with this error now:
RIGIFY ERROR: Bone 'spine.009': Cannot connect to non-chain parent rig.
Incorrect armature for type 'chain_rigs'

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/520344l0134n51g7raug3/AFTk96IKbDjs9xNx00E7FPE?rlkey=uxs7megtzu05fu0h0qfrqku1u&st=yjhp8p8t&dl=0

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Quote from CgDive on BA:

The face is a singular "building block", you can't selectively delete
parts of it

The reason you get this error is because Rigify uses metarig samples (building blocks) to build a rig, you can add them separately and build a rig from them, but you cannot delete the samples partially.
You can either remove the whole sample or delete the parts you don't want after you've generated the rig.

Related: Solution to the Rigify spine error. https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/169555/182707
